# How to merge two array of objects containing different values of same key, and also push new object into the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = [
  {
    "OwnershipNumber": 0,
    "ID": null,
    "Name": "Contractor LLC",
    "ContrEmployeeTypeId": 0,
    "ContactEmail": "",
    "ContactPhone": "",
    "VeteranEmployeeMilitaryAffiliation": "",
    "SocialSecurityNumber": "",
    "DrivingLicense": "",
    "DateOfBirth": null,
    "OwnershipPercentage": 0,
    "IsContractorActive": "Y",
    "VeteranFlag": "N",
    "VeteranEmployeeHireDate": null,
    "LegalIssueFlag": "N",
    "ActiveFlag": true,
    "TimeStamp": null
  },
  {
    "OwnershipNumber": 1878,
    "ID": null,
    "Name": "Greg Dawson",
    "ContrEmployeeTypeId": 2,
    "ContactEmail": "pra@abc.com",
    "ContactPhone": "455-455-6444",
    "VeteranEmployeeMilitaryAffiliation": null,
    "SocialSecurityNumber": "454534245",
    "DrivingLicense": "44524245",
    "DateOfBirth": "11/30/1968 12:00:00 AM",
    "OwnershipPercentage": 100,
    "IsContractorActive": "Y",
    "VeteranFlag": "N",
    "VeteranEmployeeHireDate": null,
    "LegalIssueFlag": "N",
    "ActiveFlag": true,
    "TimeStamp": null
  }
]


arr 2 = [ {"OwnershipNumber": 1878, "ContactPhone": "111-222-6444"},
 {
    "OwnershipNumber": null,
    "ID": 3,
    "SocialSecurityNumber": "465464654",
    "DrivingLicense": "464654654654",
    "DateOfBirth": "1998-12-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "VeteranEmployeeHireDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Name": "Tom Hanks",
    "ContrEmployeeTypeId": 1,
    "IsContractor": "N",
    "ContactEmail": "tom@gmail.com",
    "ContactPhone": "564-465-4654",
    "OwnershipPercentage": 100
  }
]
```

I am trying to accomplish this after merging and pushing:

```
arr3 = [
      {
        "OwnershipNumber": 0,
        "ID": null,
        "Name": "Contractor LLC",
        "ContrEmployeeTypeId": 0,
        "ContactEmail": "",
        "ContactPhone": "",
        "VeteranEmployeeMilitaryAffiliation": "",
        "SocialSecurityNumber": "",
        "DrivingLicense": "",
        "DateOfBirth": null,
        "OwnershipPercentage": 0,
        "IsContractorActive": "Y",
        "VeteranFlag": "N",
        "VeteranEmployeeHireDate": null,
        "LegalIssueFlag": "N",
        "ActiveFlag": true,
        "TimeStamp": null
      },
      {
        "OwnershipNumber": 1878,
        "ID": null,
        "Name": "Greg Dawson",
        "ContrEmployeeTypeId": 2,
        "ContactEmail": "pra@abc.com",
        "ContactPhone": "111-222-6444",
        "VeteranEmployeeMilitaryAffiliation": null,
        "SocialSecurityNumber": "454534245",
        "DrivingLicense": "44524245",
        "DateOfBirth": "11/30/1968 12:00:00 AM",
        "OwnershipPercentage": 100,
        "IsContractorActive": "Y",
        "VeteranFlag": "N",
        "VeteranEmployeeHireDate": null,
        "LegalIssueFlag": "N",
        "ActiveFlag": true,
        "TimeStamp": null
      },
{
    "OwnershipNumber": null,
    "ID": 3,
    "SocialSecurityNumber": "465464654",
    "DrivingLicense": "464654654654",
    "DateOfBirth": "1998-12-12T18:30:00.000Z",
    "VeteranEmployeeHireDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Name": "Tom Smith",
    "ContrEmployeeTypeId": 1,
    "IsContractor": "N",
    "ContactEmail": "tom@gmail.com",
    "ContactPhone": "564-465-4654",
    "OwnershipPercentage": 100
  }
    ]
```

The first array (arr1) is the master array, the second array (arr2) contains only the changes that has been done with respect to the first array (in this example you can see ownership number 1878 has a change in ContactPhone field, therefore ContactPhone along with OwnershipNumber is present in arr2, it can also include a new object like the one with name field Tom Smith (this one doesn't exist in arr 1), I am trying to merge the the change on basis of OwnershipNumber and ContactEmail  and add the new element i.e. the object which has the name field Tom Smith into the new array (arr3)). The change and inclusion of new elements is optional which means there is a case where arr 2 maybe blank. Please help me out on this.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I think the ony truly way to know with elements to have to update from arr1 and with element needs to be added from arr2 is by not having null IDs, without a unique id I think is not possible

Comment: consider using some patching libraries - for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-json-patch. It has some nice methods for comparing objects by value, generating patches and applying them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming the `OwnerdhipNumber` is a unique key to know on which object you want to make changes (or add, if this number not exist yet). In this case the below code meight work for you:

```js
const arr1 = [{"OwnershipNumber": 0,"ID": null,"Name": "Contractor LLC","ContrEmployeeTypeId": 0,"ContactEmail": "","ContactPhone": "","VeteranEmployeeMilitaryAffiliation": "","SocialSecurityNumber": "","DrivingLicense": "","DateOfBirth": null,"OwnershipPercentage": 0,"IsContractorActive": "Y","VeteranFlag": "N","VeteranEmployeeHireDate": null,"LegalIssueFlag": "N","ActiveFlag": true,"TimeStamp": null},{"OwnershipNumber": 1878,"ID": null,"Name": "Greg Dawson","ContrEmployeeTypeId": 2,"ContactEmail": "pra@abc.com","ContactPhone": "455-455-6444","VeteranEmployeeMilitaryAffiliation": null,"SocialSecurityNumber": "454534245","DrivingLicense": "44524245","DateOfBirth": "11/30/1968 12:00:00 AM","OwnershipPercentage": 100,"IsContractorActive": "Y","VeteranFlag": "N","VeteranEmployeeHireDate": null,"LegalIssueFlag": "N","ActiveFlag": true,"TimeStamp": null}];
const arr2 = [ {"OwnershipNumber": 1878, "ContactPhone": "111-222-6444"},{"OwnershipNumber": null,"ID": 3,"SocialSecurityNumber": "465464654","DrivingLicense": "464654654654","DateOfBirth": "1998-12-12T18:30:00.000Z","VeteranEmployeeHireDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","Name": "Tom Hanks","ContrEmployeeTypeId": 1,"IsContractor": "N","ContactEmail": "tom@gmail.com","ContactPhone": "564-465-4654","OwnershipPercentage": 100}];
arr2.forEach(t => {
  for(const [idx, obj] of arr1.entries()){
    if(obj.OwnershipNumber === t.OwnershipNumber) {
      // The object exist in arr1, need to update the existing object
      arr1[idx] = {...arr1[idx], ...t};
      return;
    }
  }
  // The object not already exist. we should add it to the array
  arr1.push(t);
});
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be a `unique key` in order to group your data. Here I think it could `OwnershipNumber` your unique key. Now coming to the solution, we can make use of `reduce()` to group the data:

```js
const arr1 = [{"OwnershipNumber": 0,"ID": null,"Name": "Contractor LLC","ContrEmployeeTypeId": 0,"ContactEmail": "","ContactPhone": "","VeteranEmployeeMilitaryAffiliation": "","SocialSecurityNumber": "","DrivingLicense": "","DateOfBirth": null,"OwnershipPercentage": 0,"IsContractorActive": "Y","VeteranFlag": "N","VeteranEmployeeHireDate": null,"LegalIssueFlag": "N","ActiveFlag": true,"TimeStamp": null},{"OwnershipNumber": 1878,"ID": null,"Name": "Greg Dawson","ContrEmployeeTypeId": 2,"ContactEmail": "pra@abc.com","ContactPhone": "455-455-6444","VeteranEmployeeMilitaryAffiliation": null,"SocialSecurityNumber": "454534245","DrivingLicense": "44524245","DateOfBirth": "11/30/1968 12:00:00 AM","OwnershipPercentage": 100,"IsContractorActive": "Y","VeteranFlag": "N","VeteranEmployeeHireDate": null,"LegalIssueFlag": "N","ActiveFlag": true,"TimeStamp": null}];
const arr2 = [ {"OwnershipNumber": 1878, "ContactPhone": "111-222-6444"},{"OwnershipNumber": null,"ID": 3,"SocialSecurityNumber": "465464654","DrivingLicense": "464654654654","DateOfBirth": "1998-12-12T18:30:00.000Z","VeteranEmployeeHireDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","Name": "Tom Hanks","ContrEmployeeTypeId": 1,"IsContractor": "N","ContactEmail": "tom@gmail.com","ContactPhone": "564-465-4654","OwnershipPercentage": 100}];

var result = Object.values([...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, {OwnershipNumber, ...rest})=>(
   acc[OwnershipNumber] = {...(acc[OwnershipNumber] || {}), ...{OwnershipNumber, ...rest}},
   acc
),{}));

console.log(result);
```